# Perl string match fails when it shouldn't

Tags: perl, string-comparison

I have the following code in my script.

```
if($description =~ /\'/) {
    print "I am here\n";    
    $description =~ s/\'/'/g;
}
print "description = $description\n";
```

When I run this script, I don't get the `"I am here\n"` output as the comparison fails.

But, when the `$description` string does contain an apostrophe.

`$description = "The baseball player’s spiritual redemption and recovery from drug addiction.";`

Context: I am parsing a string got from a call to nytimes bestsellers api(returned in json format) and this string is stored in `$description` string.

Comment: Add a `print $description` immediately before the if block and post the output, that will make it easier to see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: One of your premises is false. Either `$description` doesn't contain `'`, or the message is printed. Make sure that the message doesn't actually contain `’`, and keep in mind that caching could prevent the message from appearing immediately after being printed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sample string doesn't contain an apostrophe. It contains a `U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`.

It should match `/\x{2019}/`

Comment: And there is no need to escape it.

Comment: @w.k, If you don't use `\x{2019}`, you have to encode the code file using UTF-8 and add `use utf8;` to it. While it's true one doesn't have to use `\x{2019}`, is reduces the risk of errors, and it also avoids the possibility of conflating `'` and `’`.

Comment: @ikegami: context says, that the string is not defined inside of script (why to escape it if it is not from outside?). So there is actually no need for `use utf8;`. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @w.k I think the reference was to the possibility of matching it by doing something like `/['']/` and changing the second apostrophe to a literal copy of the utf8 apostrophe-like-thing.

Comment: @w.k, What string are you talking about? The only escape is in a regex pattern. Did you reply to the wrong post?

Comment: @ikegami, nope, i talk about string in `$description`, because this string is not defined in code but comes from outside (precisely by nytimes api).

Comment: @w.k, Wrong post, then. There's no `$description`, string (which doesn't have any escapes) or string literals in the post to which you replied. Please delete your comment (and I'll proceed to delete mine).

Comment: @ikegami, seems like there is some misunderstooding between us, but i am still on right track. My first comment was meant as +1 to this answer. Maybe i did not get what you meant with your comment to me then...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape quotes in regular expressions. Altering your code slightly:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $description="The baseball player's spiritual redemption and recovery from drug addiction.";

if($description =~ /'/)
{
        print "I am here\n";
        $description =~ s/'/foo/g;
}

print "description = $description\n";
```

produces the following output:

```
I am here
description = The baseball playerfoos spiritual redemption and recovery from drug addiction.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that, but the problem doesn't go away. Of course, if we put a string with apostrophe it works. But if the same string is assigned from the response given by nytimes api, the comparison fails even though the string contains an apostrophe. My guess is there might be something wrong with the encoding of string given by nytimes api. Appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: In that case, it's either an encoding issue, or (less likely), there might be invisible characters in the string.